# Unable to install Chrome extension

Tags: macos, google-chrome-extension

I'm hosting a Chrome extension on an internal Apache server, but every time I try to install it I get the following error:

```
Apps, extensions, and user scripts cannot be added from this website.
```

I've taken the following steps to try and resolve the issue:

- Made sure the file has the content type of `application/x-chrome-extension`
- Edited the `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Resources/com.google.Chrome.manifest/Contents/Resources/com.google.Chrome.manifest` as follows:

  - Set `ExtensionAllowedTypes` to  `extension`
  - Set `ExtensionInstallBlacklist` to `*`
  - Set `ExtensionInstallWhitelist` to `jigjkmgmgnpkibbhondidickedkcdjba`
  - Set `ExtensionInstallSources` to `*://*/*`

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Did you already start Chrome with the `--enable-easy-off-store-extension-install` flag?

Comment: No, I'm trying to do it with policy changes so that those changes can be pushed out to our organization. I'd like to avoid opening it up to all extensions by using the command line flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right place for the preferences file is `/Library/Managed Preferences/<username>/com.google.Chrome.plist`

You don't have to take `com.google.Chrome.manifest` as a base. That's a file describing the available options. Your file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>ExtensionInstallSources</key>
    <array><string>*://*/*</string></array>
    <key>ExtensionAllowedTypes</key>
    <array><string>extension</string></array>
    <key>ExtensionInstallBlacklist</key>
    <array><string>*</string></array>
    <key>ExtensionInstallWhitelist</key>
    <array><string>jigjkmgmgnpkibbhondidickedkcdjba</string></array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Note that the supported way of setting policy preferences is via the OS X Workgroup Manager.