# Chrome extension: allow installation from intranet server (whitelisting a url)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

On MacOS, I am getting this error while trying to install a chrome extension from an company internal url
http://intranetdomain.com/extension.crt
This is the message:

[image: Error while trying to install chrome extension]
I've followed the instructions here:
http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallSources

Opened the content of my Chrome app in Applications by right clicking the icon and choosing "Show Package Contents". I navigated and opened the policy file in: "resources/com.google.Chrome.manifest/Contents/Resources/com.google.Chrome.manifest"

Added the following lines:

```
<dict>
    <key>pfm_description</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>pfm_name</key>
    <string>ExtensionInstallSources</string>
    <key>pfm_targets</key>
    <array>
        <string>http://localhost/*</string>
        <string>http://localhost:3000/*</string>
        <string>http://intranetdomain.com/*</string>
        <string>http://intranetdomain.com:3000/*</string>
    </array>
    <key>pfm_title</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>pfm_type</key>
    <string>array</string>
</dict>
```

I restarted chrome to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Tried `--enable-easy-off-store-extension-install`?

Comment: It would be harder to change everybody chrome's links... :)

Comment: I think that you'll have more luck if you ask the question at https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/chromium-apps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to install Chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984661/unable-to-install-chrome-extension)